# JTextField.setText() throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jtextfield, settext

I'm trying to learn java and I am trying to make a simple calculator.  For some reason I am getting a `NullPointerException` on my `TextField.setText()`.

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new CalcUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    Calc c = new Calc();
    c.setVals(2,2,'+');
    result = c.doCalc();
    //need to setText(String.valueOf(c.doCalc()))
    txtScreen.setText(""+result);
    System.out.println(result);

}
```

And in my second class Calc:

```
    //sets values from calc GUI to local class vars
public void setVals(double n1, double n2, char c){
    NUM1=n1;
    NUM2=n2;
    CHAR=c;
}

//do the math
public double doCalc(){
    switch (CHAR){
        case '+':
            RESULT = NUM1+NUM2;
            break;
    }

    return RESULT;
}
```

Okay... so I send it `values(2,2)`, it and `c.doCalc()` returns `4`.  My `System.out.println(result)` prints `4` but my `txtScreen.setText(""+result);` causes a null pointer exception.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the field before using it.

```
 txtScreen = new JTextField();
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed.  Now I can't get the txtScreen.setText(""+result); to set the text.  Any ideas?

Comment: How did you change the code and whats is the error you are getting?

Comment: No errors.  It runs fine, it just doesnt change the txtScreen.  I set the my var result to 5.  So i if I print out the result it prints 4, but my txtScreen text does not change.  Here are my two lines:

Comment: txtScreen = new JTextField();
txtScreen.setText(""+result);
System.out.println(result);

Comment: it would be good for you to read some tutorials first about awt/swing. This makes sense if done in your Frame class not in the main method.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't initialized txtScreen with a value.

you need something like:

```
txtScreen = new JTextArea();
```

try posting the code where you initialize it.

Answer (score 1):

There is n existing bug in Java, various releases. In my case I have `build 1.6.0_25-b06`.  The String I pass to `JTextPane.setText()` is definitely not null, but I get a NPE within `setText()`--especially on reload. It is html, and tricky, but changing the text slightly prevents the NPE, but leaves an uneasy feeling.

There is a workaround published under the title `HTMLEditorKit throws NullPointerException when reloaded.` The workaround instantiate a (unused) `ParserDelegate{}` before the `setText()` worked for me.
http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1773568&tstart=0

Comment: Wow, thank you. This actually seems to fix the problem. Strange.